# I want to run the timer in Excel using macros serially i.e. once the D2 cell time is over then D3 cell time should start

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run the timer in Excel using macros serially i.e. once the D2 cell time is over then D3 cell time should start and then D4 like this until we have the times in D column.
As per the below code all the times are running parallel where as I want to run it sequentially.

Currently I am using below code:

```
Dim gCount As Date

Sub Timer()
    gCount = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime gCount, "ResetTime"
End Sub

Sub ResetTime()
    Dim xRng As Range
    Set xRng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
    Set xRng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D3")
    xRng.Value = xRng.Value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    If xRng.Value <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Countdown complete."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call Timer
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim gCount As Date
'Updateby20140925
Sub Timer()
gCount = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime gCount, "ResetTime"
End Sub
Sub ResetTime()
Dim xRng As Range
Set xRng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
Set xRng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D3")
xRng.Value = xRng.Value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    If xRng.Value <= 0 
    MsgBox "Countdown complete."
Exit Sub
End If
Call Timer
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I made the assumption that you want the user to see the time counting down.

I set xRng to D2 in a separate procedure ("StartTimer"). When D2 is done counting down, xRng will be set to the next cell down. Once xRng is set to an empty cell, the procedure exits.

I included message boxes after each cell is done counting down, as well as when all cells have finished to make it clear where you can add procedure calls when timers end.

```
Dim xRng As Range

Sub StartTimer()
    Set xRng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
    Call Timer
End Sub

Sub Timer()
    Dim gCount As Date
    gCount = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime gCount, "ResetTime"
End Sub

Sub ResetTime()
    If xRng.value > 0 Then
        xRng.value = xRng.value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    End If
    If xRng.value <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Countdown for " & xRng.Address & " complete."
        Set xRng = xRng.Offset(1) 'Move to next cell in column
        If xRng.value = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Countdown complete."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    Call Timer
End Sub
```

---

Edit: This updated code should satisfy your other requirements.

```
Dim xRng As Range
Dim oDict As Object

Sub StartTimer()
    Set xRng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Call PopDict
    Call Timer
End Sub

Sub Timer()
    Dim gCount As Date
    gCount = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime gCount, "ResetTime"
End Sub

Sub ResetTime()
    If xRng.value > 0 Then
        xRng.value = xRng.value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    End If
    If xRng.value <= 0 Then
        xRng.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        If xRng.Row = oDict(xRng.Offset(, -2).value) Then
            MsgBox xRng.Offset(, -2).value & " task is over. Please proceed further."
        End If
        Set xRng = xRng.Offset(1) 'Move to next cell in column
        If xRng.value = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "All tasks over."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    Call Timer
End Sub

Sub PopDict()
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = 2

    Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 2).value = vbNullString
        oDict(ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 2).value) = lRow
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Before the timer starts, this program loops through every cell in column B. When it encounters a new team name, it adds that name to a dictionary as a key. It also adds the row number for the current cell to the dictionary as an item associated with the team name (key). When it's done, the dictionary will contain a list of all team names, and with each name is the number of the last row the name appears on.

So when a timer finishes, we can check the dictionary using team name for the current row. If the current row matches the row in the dictionary, that means it's the last row for the current team, so we can notify the user.

Comment: Thanks Joku for your support. Actually I getting an error while compiling the code with the error as : Object varialble or with block variable not set at If xRng.Value > 0 Then

Comment: You need to run the procedure "StartTimer", not one of the other ones.

You're getting the error because a range hasn't been assigned to xRng yet; that's done in the "StartTimer" procedure.

Comment: Thanks Joku...It is working fine for me now..But now I am stuck with one more requirement.Request you to please help me for this -- I have column B with the team name as Development and there are many rows with Development tasks and for each and every row we have a timer.So as per the current code I am getting a popup of countdown completed for the timer column whereas I need the popup once all the timers of Development(B column) is completed and mark it in green color.  Is their a possibility we can do this?

Comment: Column A with Tasks, Column B with the Team name(Development), column C with the Flag such as Y/N , Column D as Time Required...I need to give a popup once all the tasks of development(B Column) is over and should turn into green.

Comment: So column B has a number of different team names, but you're concerned with rows where the team name is "Development". Do you want to run the timer for every task, or only Development tasks? If for every task, do you want the timers to continue if there are more after the last Development task? Which cells do you want to turn green? Do you only want them to turn green after all timers are done, or would it be better if they turned green after each timer?

Comment: Hi Joku, I want to run the timer for every task that is assigned for all the teams and  the timer should continue further but once all the tasks for a particular team is over a popup should come saying that Development task is over please proceed further and then then the timer for the next team is over a new popup should come saying that the testing task is over please proceed further like that...and once the timer for individual task is over that particular row should turn Green.

Comment: Also would like to thank you for your response and for the time you spent to understand the requirement. Thanks a lot..

Comment: I edited my answer. Be sure to scroll down in the code box to get everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot joku... Code ia working fine as per the requirement.. Thanks again.